# how to read excel file using servlet jsp

Tags: java, javascript

I had tried to read excel file from jsp to servlet in apache tomcat.
The below code has been receive excel file from apache folder after write the file and get that file.I need to dont write in apache tomcat.How to directly read excel file values.
The following code is MyServletUpload.java .

```
  import java.io.BufferedReader; 
   import java.io.BufferedWriter;
    import java.io.File;
      import java.io.FileInputStream;
  import java.io.IOException;
 import java.net.URL;
 import java.sql.Connection;
 import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
 import java.util.Iterator;
 import java.util.List;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
 import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
 import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
 import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

  import org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItem;
    import org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadException;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItemFactory;
     import org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload;
    import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
 import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
    import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
      import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

   import com.mysql.jdbc.Statement;
        import com.ppts.webwatcher.Validation.Urlvalidation;
   import com.ppts.webwatcher.setting.DBConnector;
    import com.ppts.webwatcher.webdownload.Webpagedownload;


   @WebServlet("/MyservletUpload")
    public class MyservletUpload extends HttpServlet {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private static final String DATA_DIRECTORY = "data";
private static final int MAX_MEMORY_SIZE = 1024 * 1024 * 2;
private static final int MAX_REQUEST_SIZE = 1024 * 1024;

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
 */
public MyservletUpload() {
    super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse
 *      response)
 */
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse
 *      response)
 */
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // Check that we have a file upload request
    boolean isMultipart = ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request);
    int count = 1;
    DBConnector db2Connector = DBConnector.getInstance();
    Connection con = db2Connector.getConnection(true);
    Statement stmt = null;
    String compName = null;
    String url_Name = null;
    String message = null;
    if (!isMultipart) {
        return;
    }

    // Create a factory for disk-based file items
    DiskFileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();

    // Sets the size threshold beyond which files are written directly to
    // disk.
    factory.setSizeThreshold(MAX_MEMORY_SIZE);

    // Sets the directory used to temporarily store files that are larger
    // than the configured size threshold. We use temporary directory for
    // java
    factory.setRepository(new File(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir")));

    // constructs the folder where uploaded file will be stored
    String uploadFolder = getServletContext().getRealPath("/");
    // + File.separator + DATA_DIRECTORY;

    // Create a new file upload handler
    ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);

    // Set overall request size constraint
    upload.setSizeMax(MAX_REQUEST_SIZE);

    try {
        // Parse the request
        List items = upload.parseRequest(request);
        Iterator iter = items.iterator();
        while (iter.hasNext()) {
            FileItem item = (FileItem) iter.next();

            if (!item.isFormField()) {
                String fileName = new File(item.getName()).getName();
                String filePath = uploadFolder + File.separator + fileName;
                File uploadedFile = new File(filePath);
                System.out.println("file path : " + filePath);
                item.write(uploadedFile);

                FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(uploadedFile);

                XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);

                // Get first/desired sheet from the workbook
                XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

                // Iterate through each rows one by one
                Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();
                while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
                    Row row = rowIterator.next();
                    // For each row, iterate through all the columns
                    Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
                    String h = "";
                    int i = 1;
                    while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {

                        Cell cell = cellIterator.next();
                        // Check the cell type and format accordingly

                        switch (cell.getCellType()) {
                        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                            break;
                        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                            break;
                        }
                        if (i == 1) {
                            h = cell.getStringCellValue();
                        } else {
                            h = h + "~" + cell.getStringCellValue();
                        }

                        i++;
                    }

                    String[] a = h.split("~");
                    compName = a[0].trim();
                    url_Name = a[1].trim();
                    System.out.println("company name : " + compName);
                    System.out.println("ulr name : " + url_Name);
                    try {
                        long ft1 = 0;
                        long ft2 = 0;
                        int lk = 0;

                        BufferedReader in = null;
                        BufferedWriter be = null;
                        String filenam = "";

                        String patr = getServletContext().getRealPath("/");
                        filenam = patr + "webfolder";
                        // System.out.println("part : " + filenam);
                        File filchkr = new File(filenam);
                        if (filchkr.exists()) {
                            // System.out.println("fil exists");
                        } else {
                            // System.out.println("fil not exists");
                        }

                        try {

                            ft1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
                            String line1;
                            // String arrsp =
                            // "http://www.mmrf.org/research/research.html~helwel131";

                            int li = compName.length();

                            // System.out.println("Urlname " + url_Name);

                            // System.out.println("companyname " +
                            // compName);

                            System.out.println("@@@@"
                                    + Urlvalidation.checkInsertValidation(
                                            url_Name, compName));

                            if (Urlvalidation.checkInsertValidation(
                                    url_Name, compName) != null) {

                                System.out
                                        .println("error url name >>>>>>>>> "
                                                + url_Name);
                                System.out
                                        .println("errror url link >>>>>>>>>>>"
                                                + compName);

                            } else {

                                String urlreplaceText = url_Name.replace(
                                        " ", "%20");
                                // System.out.println("path : "+getServletContext().getRealPath("/"));
                                URL url1 = new URL(urlreplaceText);
                                // System.out.println(url1);
                                String filepath = filenam + "/" + compName;
                                File f1 = new File(filepath);

                                if (!f1.exists()) {
                                }
                                boolean result = false;

                                try {
                                    f1.mkdir();
                                    result = true;
                                } catch (SecurityException se) {
                                    // handle it
                                }
                                String fullpath = filepath
                                        + "/firstdownload.html";

                                Webpagedownload.webdown(fullpath, url1);

                                lk = 1;
                                ft2 = System.currentTimeMillis();

                                long ft = ft2 - ft1;
                                // System.out.println(ft + ": time ");

                                String selection = "full_content";
                                java.util.Date now = new java.util.Date();
                                String DATE_FORMAT = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss";
                                SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(
                                        DATE_FORMAT);
                                String strDateNew = sdf.format(now);
                                stmt = (Statement) con.createStatement();
                                String sql = "INSERT INTO new_table (title,url,source_selection,content,inserttime,insertvalue) VALUES ('"
                                        + compName
                                        + "','"
                                        + url_Name
                                        + "','"
                                        + selection
                                        + "','','"
                                        + strDateNew + "','" + '0' + "')";
                                stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
                                HttpSession session = request.getSession();
                                String username = String.valueOf(session
                                        .getAttribute("username"));
                                String userid = String.valueOf(session
                                        .getAttribute("userid"));

                                stmt.executeUpdate("insert into usersession(userid,username,createtime,urlname,urllink) values('"
                                        + userid
                                        + "','"
                                        + username
                                        + "','"
                                        + strDateNew
                                        + "','"
                                        + compName
                                        + "','" + url_Name + "')");

                            }

                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            System.out.println("Error: \t" + e);
                            System.out
                                    .println("exception Urlname>>>>>>>>> "
                                            + url_Name);
                            System.out
                                    .println("exception companyname >>>>>>>>>>>"
                                            + compName);
                        }

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        System.out.println(e);
                    }
                    count++;

                }

                message = "success";
                File file = new File(filePath);

                file.delete();

            }
        }

        getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/Message.jsp").forward(
                request, response);

    } catch (FileUploadException ex) {
        throw new ServletException(ex);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        throw new ServletException(ex);
    }
}
```

}

```
  jsp 
      <form method="post" action="MyservletUpload"
                    enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    Choose File : <input type="file" name="photo" size="50" /> <input
                        type="submit" value="Upload" onclick="uppload()">


                </form>



                    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
                        pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
                    <%@ page import="java.sql.*,java.util.*,java.io.*"%>
                    <%@ page import="com.ppts.webwatcher.setting.*"%>
                    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
                    <html>
                    <head>



                    <script type="text/javascript"
                        src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>




                    <script type="text/javascript">

                    function Pager(tableName, itemsPerPage) {

                    this.tableName = tableName;

                    this.itemsPerPage = itemsPerPage;

                    this.currentPage = 1;

                    this.pages = 0;

                    this.inited = false;

                    this.showRecords = function(from, to) {

                    var rows = document.getElementById(tableName).rows;

                    // i starts from 1 to skip table header row

                    for (var i = 1; i < rows.length; i++) {

                    if (i < from || i > to)

                    rows[i].style.display = 'none';

                    else

                    rows[i].style.display = '';

                    }

                    }

                    this.showPage = function(pageNumber) {

                    if (! this.inited) {

                    alert("not inited");

                    return;

                    }

                    var oldPageAnchor = document.getElementById('pg'+this.currentPage);

                    oldPageAnchor.className = 'pg-normal';

                    this.currentPage = pageNumber;

                    var newPageAnchor = document.getElementById('pg'+this.currentPage);

                    newPageAnchor.className = 'pg-selected';

                    var from = (pageNumber - 1) * itemsPerPage + 1;

                    var to = from + itemsPerPage - 1;

                    this.showRecords(from, to);

                    }

                    this.prev = function() {

                    if (this.currentPage > 1)

                    this.showPage(this.currentPage - 1);

                    }

                    this.next = function() {

                    if (this.currentPage < this.pages) {

                    this.showPage(this.currentPage + 1);

                    }

                    }

                    this.init = function() {

                    var rows = document.getElementById(tableName).rows;

                    var records = (rows.length - 1);

                    this.pages = Math.ceil(records / itemsPerPage);

                    this.inited = true;

                    }

                    this.showPageNav = function(pagerName, positionId) {

                    if (! this.inited) {

                    alert("not inited");

                    return;

                    }

                    var element = document.getElementById(positionId);

                    var pagerHtml = '<span onclick="' + pagerName + '.prev();" class="pg-normal"> « Prev </span> ';

                    for (var page = 1; page <= this.pages; page++)

                    pagerHtml += '<span id="pg' + page + '" class="pg-normal" onclick="' + pagerName + '.showPage(' + page + ');">' + page + '</span> ';

                    pagerHtml += '<span onclick="'+pagerName+'.next();" class="pg-normal"> Next »</span>';

                    element.innerHTML = pagerHtml;

                    }

                    }

                    </script>
                    <SCRIPT language="javascript">
                    $(function(){

                        // add multiple select / deselect functionality
                        $("#selectall").click(function () {
                              $('.case').attr('checked', this.checked);
                        });

                        // if all checkbox are selected, check the selectall checkbox
                        // and viceversa
                        $(".case").click(function(){

                            if($(".case").length == $(".case:checked").length) {
                                $("#selectall").attr("checked", "checked");
                            } else {
                                $("#selectall").removeAttr("checked");
                            }

                        });
                    });
                    </SCRIPT>

                    <style>
                    .textbox {
                        background:
                            url(data:image/png;base64,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)
                            no-repeat 10px 4px #FFF;
                        height: 25px;
                        width: 275px;
                        border: 1px solid #848484;
                        padding-left: 30px;
                    }
                    </style>


                    <title>UPDATE SCANNER-Updated Url</title>
                    </head>
                    <%@ include file="header.jsp"%>
                    <body>
                        <SCRIPT language="JavaScript">
                    function OnSubmitForm()
                    {
                        if(document.pressed == 'Send Email')
                        {
                            document.myform.action ="emailaction.jsp";

                        }
                        else
                        if(document.pressed == 'View')
                        {


                            var slvals = [];
                            $('input:checkbox[name=case]:checked').each(function() {
                                slvals.push($(this).val());

                            });
                            var i;
                            for (i = 0; i < slvals.length; i++) {
                                var url="Multitabhelp.jsp?urlid="+slvals[i];
                                var win = window.open(url, '_blank');
                                  win.focus();
                            }

                             return false;


                        }
                        return true;
                    }
                    </SCRIPT>
                        <center>
                            <b><h1>Updated URL</h1> </b>


                            <FORM name="myform" onSubmit="return OnSubmitForm();">
                                <%
                                    int co = 1;
                                    DBConnector db2Connector = DBConnector.getInstance();
                                    Connection conn = db2Connector.getConnection(false);
                                    Statement stmt = null;
                                    Statement stmt1 = null;
                                    String time;
                                    String urld = request.getParameter("urlid");
                                    System.out.println("hello " + urld);
                                    try {

                                        stmt = conn.createStatement();
                                        stmt1 = conn.createStatement();
                                        String son = "";
                                        String b = "";
                                        String sww = "select * from updatehistory where updatetime='"
                                                + urld + "' and updation='1'";
                                        System.out.println(sww);
                                        ResultSet rs = stmt
                                                .executeQuery("select * from updatehistory where updatetime='"
                                                        + urld + "' and updation='1'");
                                        out.println("<div class='CSSTableGenerator'>");
                                        out.println("<TABLE BORDER=1 id=\"tablepaging\" class=\"yui\" align=\"center\">");
                                        out.println("<th>"
                                                + "  S.No"
                                                + "</th>");
                                        out.println("<th>"
                                                + "  Date"
                                                + "</th>");
                                        out.println("<th>"
                                                + "  Source Name"
                                                + "</th>");
                                        out.println("<th>"
                                                + "  URL"
                                                + "</th>");
                                        out.println("<th>"
                                                + " Updated Content"
                                                + "</th>");
                                %>
                                <th><input type="checkbox" id="selectall" /></th>
                                <%
                                    out.println("<th>"
                                                + " <label class='col-md-3 control-label'> Action</label>"
                                                + "</th>");
                                        while (rs.next()) {

                                            time = rs.getString("date_time");

                                            ResultSet rs11 = stmt1
                                                    .executeQuery("select * from new_table where urlid='"
                                                            + rs.getString("urlid") + "' ");
                                            if (rs11.next()) {
                                                System.out.println(rs11.getInt(1));
                                                out.println("<TR>");

                                                out.println("<TD>" + co + "</TD>");
                                                out.println("<TD>" + rs.getString("date_time")
                                                        + "</TD>");
                                                out.println("<TD>" + rs11.getString("title")
                                                        + "</a></TD>");
                                                out.println("<TD>" + rs11.getString("url")
                                                        + "</a></TD>");
                                                out.println("<TD>" + rs11.getString("updatecontent")
                                                        + "</a></TD>");
                                %>
                                <td><input type="checkbox" class="case" name="case" id="chease"
                                    value="<%=rs.getString("urlid")%>"></td>
                                <%
                                    out.println("<TD><a href=\"Showupdate.jsp?urlid="
                                                        + rs.getString("urlid") + "\" >VIEW </a></TD>");
                                            }
                                %>






                                <%
                                    out.println("</TD>");

                                            out.println("</TR>");
                                            co++;

                                        }
                                        out.println("</TABLE>");
                                        if (co < 2) {
                                            System.out.println("************" + co);
                                            out.println("<center> NO UPDATES </center>");
                                        }

                                        out.print("</div");
                                    } finally {
                                        try {

                                            conn.close();
                                        } catch (SQLException se) {
                                        }
                                    }
                                %>


                                <br> Enter Email ID : <input type="text" class="textbox"
                                    name="email"> <INPUT TYPE="SUBMIT" name="Operation"
                                    onClick="document.pressed=this.value" VALUE="Send Email"> <br>
                                <br> <br> Click to View Selected Update Link... <INPUT
                                    TYPE="SUBMIT" name="Operation" onClick="document.pressed=this.value"
                                    VALUE="View">
                            </FORM>
                            <br> <br>
                            <div id="pageNavPosition" style="padding-top: 20px" align="center">
                            </div>
                            <br>
                        </center>
                        <script type="text/javascript"><!--
                    var pager = new Pager('tablepaging', 10);
                    pager.init();
                    pager.showPageNav('pager', 'pageNavPosition');
                    pager.showPage(1);
                    </script>


                        <%@ include file="footer.jsp"%>
                    </body>
                    </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Better to use Apache POI and do one thing if you are not using maven download the below jars and keep it in your lib

**dom4j-1.6.1.jar,
poi-3.9-20121203.jar,
poi-ooxml-3.9-20121203.jar,
poi-ooxml-schemas-3.9-20121203.jar,
xmlbeans-2.3.0.jar**

and then using some classes you can read excel file even a row wise or cell wise

Try this I Hope this will you.....

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps`

```
    public class ReadExcelfile {
      public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
        Statement stmt = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:employee").createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt
            .executeQuery("select lastname, firstname, id from [Sheet1$]");
        while (rs.next()) {
          String lname = rs.getString(1);
          String fname = rs.getString(2);
          int id = rs.getInt(3);
          System.out.println(fname + " " + lname + "  id : " + id);
        }
        rs.close();
        stmt.close();
      }
    }
```

`